# How to set cron path?? Any easy way

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I set 
use /usr/local/bin/php /home2/bollyzz1/public_html/Bollyzz/latest_auditions_by_email.php

Error:
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: use: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Login to your cPanel and click Cronjobs under the Advanced section

Enter the following command in the Command to run field.

```
lynx -source "http://www.yourdomain.com/Bollyzz/latest_auditions_by_email.php" > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your crone file path like this.

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home2/bollyzz1/public_html/Bollyzz/latest_auditions_by_email.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Use wget command

```
wget http://domain.com/latest_auditions_by_email.php
```

set your time ( * * * * *)  and check